# How to query and sort data with 2 $in operators using only index covered query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection "activities" with model:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId,
   action: String,
   userId: ObjectId,
   time: Date
}
```

I have a query:

```
db.activities.find({
   action: {
      $in: [
          "1stAction",
          "2ndAction",
          ...,
          "20thAction",
      ]
   },
   userId: {
      $in: [
          ObjectId("1stUserId"),
          ObjectId("2ndUserId"),
          ...,
          ObjectId("500thUserId"),
      ]
   },
   time: {
      $lt: new Date()
   }
}).sort({
   time: -1
}).limit(20)
```

Now I have an compound index {userId: 1, action: 1, time: -1}
I guarantee that the index is not multikey one (So it doesnt contain Array values).

The problem starts when count of (actions * userIds) is greater than 200.

When count is below of 200 then mongodb splits every unique pair of userId+action to separated index covered query and after getting a result performs SORT_MERGE clause and finishes very fast.

When count is greater than 200 (can be changed from default by setting **internalQueryMaxScansToExplode** option in mongoDB config file) then mongoDB performs a query with fetching documents and doesn't use index only. So it works very slowly.
I can't increase internalQueryMaxScansToExplode setting by recommendation of mongoDB team([SERVER-24314](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24314)) because it causes server crash.

I tried to build another index {time: -1, userId: 1, action: 1} but, unfortunately, I have too many records in the collection that a query even using an index takes 30 seconds at least and scans 30 000 000 index entries. It is not acceptable as well.

I would like to fetch documents by 20 actions and 500 users in one query.

What is the best solution for this problem?